# $L^2$ norm of antiderivative

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Assume 
$$
f\in L^2[0,1], g(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt,
$$
How to prove that
$$
\|g\|_2\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\|f\|_2
$$
I think it should be solved with Holder Inequality and double integral, but I don't know where the $\sqrt{2}$ comes from? Thanks!

Comment: $\int_0^1 x\,dx= \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$ |g(x)| = \left|\int_0^x f(t)\,dt\right| \le \int_0^x |f(t)|\,dt = \langle |f|,\chi_{[0,x]}\rangle \le \sqrt{\langle |f|,|f|\rangle \langle\chi_{[0,x]},\chi_{[0,x]}\rangle}. $$

Note then that $\langle \chi_{[0,x]},\chi_{[0,x]}\rangle = x.$ I imagine you can take it from here.

Comment: Oh, yes! I have never thought the antiderivative could be transformed to such presentation. Thank you very much!

Comment: Any time $L^2$ comes up with integrals like this, Cauchy-Schwarz and that trick I used should come to mind immediately!